# Implement Multitasking functionality in samsung tizen tv application

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-web-simulator

We have developed Samsung tizen tv application.

Now our client want to submit application on Tizen app store.

We have compared functionality of our application with Development Checklist using url http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/development-checklist/ .

We have found that we missed multitasking functionality in our application.

Can we implement Multitasking functionality for Samsung Tizen TV application ?

If yes, then how to implement Multitasking functionality ?

**One more query**,
Can we submit application without Multitasking functionality to tizen store ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable Multitasking in the config.xml. Be sure you add the following line:

Multitasking is enabled on config.xml as follows:

In adition, you need to listen the hide event (every time you change to a different app document.hidden is triggered) and include a behaviour (typically you will pause your video player):

```
if(document.hidden){
    //when application is hidden (multitasking)
    webapis.avplay.suspend(); 
  } else {
    //when application is restored
    webapis.avplay.restore(); 
  }
});
```

Kind regards

Comment: By the way, multitasking is mandatory since third quarter 2016.

Comment: Did you mean to include this code to include in the config.xml? <tizen:metadata key='http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/multitasking.support' value='true' />

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean. Somehow that line of code is gone from my response, sorry for that.